# Node.js: Is there a deploy module could merge javascript file and minify them?

Tags: node.js, compression, minify, web-deployment

Is there a deploy module in node.js could merge my javascript and css file

or compress javascript and css file and so on.

cuz I deploy my application at `Platform-as-a-Service` like `appfog`

so I can't expect the server itself could help me do that

mybe the module could?

Comment: Take a look at http://gruntjs.com/ It can merge and minify your javascript files. I am not sure how you can hook it to your appfog deployment process, though.

Comment: [Uglify JS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) is also good

Answer (score 1):

This article on underappreciated NPM commands looks to skim over just what you're looking for. Specifically the ability to use preinstall hooks:

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "./bin/custom-script.sh"
}
```

http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2012/12/11/underappreciated-npm-commands/